# How do you diagnose write_concern problems in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine, database

I have a Mongo database (v2.4.10) setup with a secondary and I'm saving data to it. Occassionally after saving a new document and trying to retrieve it I get an exception for the document not being found, even though on manual inspection it's there.

Here's a minmal example but unfortunately the problem does not reproduce consistently. I suspect the problem due to trying to read from the database before the secondary has a copy of the data?

```
from mongoengine import connect, Document

class User(Document):
    date_creation = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    username = StringField(required=True, unique=True)

user = User()
user.username = 'nick'
user.save()

user = User.objects.get(username='nick') # exception thrown here matching User not found
user.username = 'changed'
user.save()
```

Is there a way to diagnose whether this is true? Is so what is the recommended solution should I just be calling `user.save(write_concern={'w':0})`

Comment: Because you want it to be propagated to the secondary as well, you need it to be [replica acknowledged](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/#replica-acknowledged)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you saying that my diagnosis of the problem is correct, but that it shouldn't be write_concern {'w':0} and rather {'w':2} which is replica acknowledged. I thought that was the default actually?

Comment: yes, you are right. I think that your diagnoses is correct (I can not be sure, but it sounds reasonable). And yes, you should change it to `2`. As far as I remember default is 0 (but a brief search on write concern in 2.4 does not reveal it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ***save(..., write_concern={w: 2, fsync: True}, ...)***
as mongoengine write concern by default is [None](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document.save).